# ReportViewer MVC Core

Tags: relatório, reportviewer, asp.net-core

Estou trabalhando em um projeto utilizando o ASP.NET MVC Core.

Instalei todas as dependências necessárias para a utilização, porém o mesmo não habilita para ser usado na minha aplicação. Entretanto, se eu crio uma nova aplicação MVC5 ele está habilitado e instalado.

Alguém já passou por isso?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Atualização 2023

Para .NET Core 3.1+ há uma solução.

Com a inclusão do WinForms no .NET Core 3.1 e no .NET 5 como um substituto para o .NET Framework, tornou-se viável portar os aplicativos de desktop de negócios existentes para o .NET Core SDK para se beneficiar dos novos recursos C# e JIT.

[ReportViewer Core](https://github.com/lkosson/reportviewercore)

Ainda assim, tenha em mente que não é uma biblioteca oficial da Microsoft, uma vez que o time ainda diz que não tem planos de lançamento de pacotes oficiais de serviços de relatórios ou do próprio Report Viewer para .NET Core.

> Obrigado por entrar em contato conosco. Isso não é algo que planejamos fazer. [Fala de mkArtakMSFT 1](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/22304)

> Estamos encerrando este problema, pois não é diretamente relevante para este repositório e, com base nos comentários aqui, a equipe do SSRS já está ciente desse feedback. Dada a quantidade de comentários que recebeu, agora é incontrolável. [Fala de mkArtakMSFT 2](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/1528)

---

#### Resposta original

Não funciona e por enquanto não irá funcionar na versão Core do ASP.NET.

A Microsoft está apenas avaliando a criação de um controle .NET Core ReportViewer. O que significa que não há nenhum presente (08/2017).
Também não existe nenhum "controle" do ReportViewer para o ASP.NET MVC.

#### Solução 1

Existe uma solução alternativa de Alan Juden em torno do ReportExecution.asmx do MS-ReportServer.

- [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AlanJuden.MvcReportViewer.NetCore/)
- [Como instalar e configurar](http://alanjuden.com/2016/11/10/mvc-net-core-report-viewer/)

Mas não é a mesma coisa. Isso ainda exigirá Autenticação do Windows no servidor de relatório (juntamente com o-usuário-deve-ser-membro-do-grupo-de-anúncios-específico), e um servidor SSRS rodando no Windows. Ou seja, você precisará de um servidor de relatórios para que seu "ReportViewer" funcione.

- Traduzido e adaptado de: [Can one use Reportviewer Control in ASP.net Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35890414/can-one-use-reportviewer-control-in-asp-net-core)

#### Solução 2

Há ainda outra solução disponível através do seguinte `nuget`:

- [Microsoft.AspNetCore.ReportViewer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.ReportViewer/1.0.2)

Porém, conforme a solução anterior, ainda é necessário fazer autenticação em um servidor de relatórios. Conforme a descrição do próprio `nuget`:

> Renderização de relatórios para .Net Core MVC através de um servidor de relatórios. Apenas com suporte remoto, relatórios locais irão chegar futuramente.

#### Solução 3

Parece que o Telerik criou uma solução através de relatórios HTML5 para o ASP.NET Core. O único problema é que as bibliotecas do Telerik necessitam ser compradas.

- [HTML5 Report Viewer in ASP.NET Core](http://docs.telerik.com/reporting/html5-report-viewer-asp-net-core)