# Gerar relatórios em ASPNET CORE MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

Existe alguma solução para gerar relatórios em aplicações ASPNET CORE 2.0 MVC sem precisar de um servidor de relatórios?
Fiz algumas buscas e não encontrei muito coisa sobre o assunto.

Comment: Que tipo de relatório? exportar para Excel, PDF.. etc?

Comment: Da mesma forma como faria qualquer aplicação, perdendo as ferramentas de visualização que o Report Server já tem, você teria que construir tudo...

Comment: Qual é exatamente a sua dúvida?

Comment: Sou iniciante no desenvolvimento WEB, pelo que pesquisei nas versão "CORE" do aspnet não tem uma solução nativa para gerar relatórios.
Vocês podem me indicar um tutorial ou algum material? A ideia é que o usuário consiga visualizar um relatório de estoque, por exemplo.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [ReportViewer MVC Core](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/199055/reportviewer-mvc-core)

Comment: Pode gerar PDF e abrir em uma guia? E pode ser em javascript?

Comment: pode sim, só estou procurando uma forma de fazer isso.

Comment: Caso seu servidor seja Linux ou não possa armazenar os executaveis do wkhtmltopdf, pode ulitzar o JSReport. https://jsreport.net/learn/dotnet-aspnetcore

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o Rotativa Asp Net Core, em suma, ele converte as views em .cshtml para .pdf utilizando o wkhtmltopdf, utilização bem simples, utilizo em todas minhas aplicações.

Links:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rotativa.AspNetCore/1.1.1

https://github.com/webgio/Rotativa.AspNetCore

Exempo de Utilização

```
var relatorio = new ViewAsPdf("Print")
{
    PageOrientation = Rotativa.AspNetCore.Options.Orientation.Landscape,
    PageSize = Rotativa.AspNetCore.Options.Size.A4,
    PageMargins = { Left = 05, Right = 05 },
    Model = model
};
return relatorio;
```